# Did HP Lovecraft ever publish a novel?

Tags: h-p-lovecraft

From what I've read HPL exclusively published (or at least submitted) his works to periodicals and magazines. Were any of his works primarily published, primarily as a book?

Comment: How long do you mean fo a novel?  Some of his stories are over 100 pages in length.

Comment: It's not the length but the form of publishing. To my knowledge the longer stories of his were published in chapters in periodicals such as Weird Tales.

Comment: @Pureferret, it is important to understand that at this time in literary history fantasy and science fiction were considered low-brow kids-stuff, but never-the-less consumed by adults too. They were a lot like comic books were until recently. The old pulps were often the only way to get the stuff published at all, regardless of quality.

Comment: @DampeS8N I'm quite aware of that, and in fact some/most of his tales from what I've read were rejected several times before being published in the pulps (correct term?). This is why I'm so curious about this particular part of his publishing history.

Comment: The wiki entry for _The Shadow Over Innsmouth_ says that's the only novella which was published during his lifetime which did not appear in a periodical. Is this the kind of thing you mean?

Comment: @ThomBrannan yes exactly!

Comment: The usual break point for "novel" is 60,000 words.  At least to the publishing industry.  *Charles Dexter Ward* is a "short novel" by word count -- very long for a novella (which typically run 10,000 to 30,000 words), but under the magic 60,000.  Length affects ability to publish, too, because too short will seem too "thin" for buyers to be willing to pay novel price, and without novel price, it's hard to make a profit on the work.  Ace Doubles were often "short novels" and publishable by putting two in a single cover.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to his [bibliography on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H._P._Lovecraft_bibliography), [The Case of Charles Dexter Ward](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Case_of_Charles_Dexter_Ward) and The Inevitable Conflict¹ are the closest you'll find.

It was first published after his death in the [Weird Tales](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weird_Tales) periodical, but has since been republished as a novel.

Here's two of the covers it's had:

[image: "The Case of Charles Dexter Ward". The cover shows an eye inside a triangle, which is located inside a circle against a red background.][image: "The Case of Charles Dexter Ward". The cover shows a pile of skulls and bones against a black background.]

¹I can't seem to find much information on The Inevitable Conflict, but it appears to also have been first published in another periodical.  [One site](http://www.wilmarthcafe.org/library/lovecraft/) claims it may not have even been written by Lovecraft.

Comment: [This cover](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a0/At_the_mountains_of_madness.jpg) is confusing. Wiki lists it as a novella, but I thought it was worth pointing out.

Comment: @MeatTrademark I know little about "novel", "novella", etc, but Wikipedia indicates that the Italian word "novella" is the source of the English word "novel"

Comment: @Izkata - In English the distinction is just length - a novella is short compared to a novel but longer than a short story. It might take several issues in an SF magazine to appear, but still be too short to bind alone into a book as a stand-alone novel. The CD Ward novel is very short.

Comment: Lovecraft unquestionably did not write *The Inevitable Conflict*.